# Persistant MySQL connection in Python for social media harvesting

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python to stream large amounts of Twitter data into a MySQL database.  I anticipate my job running over a period of several weeks.  I have code that interacts with the twitter API and gives me an iterator that yields lists, each list corresponding to a database row.  What I need is a means of maintaining a persistent database connection for several weeks.  Right now I find myself having to restart my script repeatedly when my connection is lost, sometimes as a result of MySQL being restarted.

Does it make the most sense to use the mysqldb library, catch exceptions and reconnect when necessary?  Or is there an already made solution as part of sqlalchemy or another package?  Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right answer is to try and handle the connection errors; it sounds like you'd only be pulling in a much a larger library just for this feature, while trying and catching is probably how it's done, whatever level of the stack it's at. If necessary, you could multithread these things since they're probably IO-bound (i.e. suitable for Python GIL threading as opposed to multiprocessing) and decouple the production and the consumption with a queue, too, which would maybe take some of the load off of the database connection.

Comment: I wrote a small MySQLdb wrapper based on this idea: https://gist.github.com/selahlynch/5fcd7ce5c04eb1771eda